# System.FormatException: 'The input string '' was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, ado.net

Keep getting this exception when I try to see my products list.
I'm using ADO. Net in this case and I'm really unfamiliar with it

```
public List<Product> GetAll()
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    sql.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = sql.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = "Select * from Products";
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        products.Add(new Product
                        {
                            Id = int.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString()),
                            Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                            Brand = reader["Brand"].ToString(),
                            Price = int.Parse(reader["Price"].ToString()),
                            CartId = int.Parse(reader["CartId"].ToString()),
                            FactorId = int.Parse(reader["FactorId"].ToString())
                        });
                    }
                    reader.Close();

                    return products;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It means that highly  likely the string is not something `int.Parse` can deal with. So find which one and in which case and act accordingly.

Comment: It would help if you sent definition of Product class and also the DB table. It seems like the class property types don't match the parsed vales

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely throwing the error when you're trying to parse a string to an integer. Use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse` will return a boolean indicating if the parsing was successful or not. The parsed value is returned via the `out` parameter.

Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-8.0) for more information.